# In Make, how to make a recipe fail only on specific exit codes?

Tags: makefile, grep, continuous-integration

I have a recipe in my Makefile that returns 0, 1 or 2. I want the recipe to succeed if its command returns 1, and fail in all other cases. I can use `!` to invert the status, but I would like to fail when recipe returns 2 as well as 0.

**My specific use case:** I have spell-checking as part of my build process. The best I've been able to do so far is this:

```
.md.html:
    ! $(ASPELL) list -p $(DICT_FILE) < $< | $(GREP) -nFf - $<
    $(PANDOC) -o $@ $<
```

`aspell(1)` produces a list of words it doesn't understand and pipes it to `grep(1)`. `grep(1)` prints them with user-friendly line numbers for the author to find easily in markdown source. `aspell(1)` always returns 0, regardless of matches. `grep(1)`'s man page says:

> exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the check yourself, in shell syntax.  Like this:

```
.md.html:
        $(ASPELL) list -p $(DICT_FILE) < $< | $(GREP) -nFf - $<; [ $$? -eq 1 ]
        $(PANDOC) -o $@ $<
```

The test will be true (and exit with success) only if the exit code from the previous command (the grep) is exactly 1.

Comment: That's pretty clever!